# How to separate longest patterns of repeating characters within a sequence where each pattern can be separated by unknown amount of characters?

Tags: python

Given a list of characters `[A,B,C,D,A,E,F,B,C,G,D]`

What would be the way to seperate the longest pattern `[A,B,C,D]` and also return the characters `[E,F,G]` in right order?

Another example `[A,B,E,C,D,A,F,B,C,J,C,D]` would extract longest repeating pattern `[A,B,C,D]` and also return `[E,F,C,J]`

The solution would be in Python.

Comment: What is the definition of the longest repeating pattern?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you want to just remove the elements of the list that is present in another list

```
>>> lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'F', 'B', 'C', 'G', 'D']
>>> ptrn = set(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
>>> [e for e in lst if e not in ptrn]
['E', 'F', 'G']
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know beforehand that the pattern is ABCD, it could be some other generic pattern that starts with A and ends with D.

Comment: I have defined the ptrn just as an example. whatever your ptrn is, just convert it to a set and then use the list comprehension

Comment: You answered my question, thanks. I will have to create a new question later with a better problem formulation. The problem I am trying to solve is to find and then separate the pattern. So the key problem is finding the pattern in the first place.